# Imposing follow-up time cutoffs on censored data for cox regression

Tags: cox-model, censoring

When fitting cox regression models, is it valid to impose a cutoff for censored samples to have been followed for at least a given stretch of time for inclusion in the analysis?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? An advantage of Cox models is that it includes information from all cases, censored or not. Do you expect there to be some non-proportionality of hazards at very early times?

Comment: There is very heavy censoring that disproportionately affects one of the three groups I am comparing, with some of the samples being advanced disease; there is a possibility they might have been lost to follow-up because of adverse outcomes.

Comment: Do you have any way to determine, for the censored cases, whether/when there was an "adverse outcome" that would lead to lost follow-up? If so, it might be possible to do a competing-risk analysis. Otherwise, it's not clear to me how to proceed fairly. Simply removing the short-follow-up cases will bias against those who had such an "adverse outcome." You might want to consider posting a new question that specifies the underlying problem you have, which is disproportionate censoring among groups. I don't have experience with that, but others on this site certainly do.